# How to set padding but keep the element responsive?

Tags: html, reactjs, responsive-design, padding, react-bootstrap

I want to set padding on a element but then when I resize the window I clearly see that this element isn't responsive anymore. I use Reactjs with React-bootstrap and it comes from the way I set the padding on my element because if I remove it, then it's responsive.

```
<div style={{padding: '50px 300px 100px 300px'}} className="col-md-12 offset-md-12 card">
   <p style={{textAlignVertical: "center", textAlign: "center", fontSize: 22, color: "green"}}>File processed with success</p>
   <a href="/" className="button" style={{textAlignVertical: "center", textAlign: "center", fontSize: 16, color: "blue"}}>Go back home</a>
</div>
```

How can I set padding and keep the element responsive ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use Percentage as a measurement Unit. The percentage will set the area according to a specific percent on a screen, while pixels will take some specific area of your screen that will not be responsive.

Example

```
 style={{padding: '5% 3% 1% 3%'}}
```

Comment: That's also a nice input I'll use it aswell on some other elements. Thanks